# console doctrine:migrations:diff errors with "No columns specified for table table "

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using php 7.1.9 and doctrine migration 1.5.0 and doctrine migration bundle with symfony 3

I've been using the command `console doctrine:migrations:diff` fine until today and now I have the error :

```
22:26:28 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:migrations:diff". Message: "No columns specified for table table" ["error" => Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException { …},"command" => "doctrine:migrations:diff","message" => "No columns specified for table table"] []
```

Is this error message related to some potential causes ?

(I know the question is vague, but I couldn't find on the internet links corresponding to this error message, so I hope I can fill a gap)

Comment: can you post your entity for migration?

Comment: @starnzd see my answer, actually as I was trying to provide more context to this answer, I found my mistake :/

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem:

On my postgresql database I had created a table named `table` with 0 columns, it was accepted by postgresql but it was creating an exception in doctrine migrations , as doctrine throw an exception for the case of a table without columns.

So even though my PHP code had not been touched, as doctrine migration create a "DROP TABLE" statement for tables that are not linked with an Entity, it was failing.